I want to quit the app using python's flet
I am developing an Android app using Python's flet. As a function, I need to perform a process to terminate the app. In flutter, it seems that you can terminate an app with SystemNavigator.pop(), but is there an equivalent in flet?
Research on SystemNavigator.pop() in flet
There was no exact same functionality

You generally don't terminate Android apps (or mobile apps in general).  You let the user navigate away, and the OS will terminate you when resources are low.

Flet currently do not have any direct way of terminating an app, but I know a workaround. It will shut down the app immediately.
import os

def terminate_app():
    os._exit(0)

No cleanup, direct termination. It's like hitting ALT+F4 in game. Best of luck.
